# Queries results intersection check for automatic cache invalidation

Tags: sql, caching, memcached, resultset, middleware

**Problem**

I'm programming an automatic caching middleware between an Java Application and Database. 
I parse the queries, obtain query MD5 hash and store CachedResultSet in key-value service.

I would like to implement an automatic cache invalidation on updates to given result set.
To do so, I would have to check if INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE query affects results of a SELECT query which result is cached.

**Example**

Let's say I have following SELECT queries:

*Q1* - `SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE TEST_COLUMN > 1500 AND TEST_COLUMN_2 = 'TEST';`

*Q2* - `SELECT TEST_COLUMN_2 FROM TEST;`

I cache the result sets.
Then UPDATEs:

*Q3* - `UPDATE TEST SET TEST_COLUMN_2='TEST' WHERE TEST_COLUMN<1000;`

*Q4* - `UPDATE TEST SET TEST_COLUMN_2='TEST2';`

*Q3* does not affect *Q1* result set, therefore no cache invalidation is required.

*Q3* affects *Q2* result set, therefore cache invalidation is required.

*Q4* affects *Q1*, *Q2* result set, therefore cache invalidation is required

**Simplest solution**

The simplest solution would be to store all queries that are run on the given table using columns in form of a map, where * means all columns:

```
DATABASE_A: {
    SCHEMA_A:{
        TABLE_TEST:{ 
            *:[Q1],              // invalidated by: Q3,Q4
            TEST_COLUMN:[Q1],    // invalidated by: none -> used as condition in Q3
            TEST_COLUMN2:[Q1,Q2] // invalidated by: Q3,Q4
         },
        TABLE_TEST2: {
            *:[Qx]
        }
    }
}
```

So if an update occurs on column TEST_COLUMN2 in table TEST, then query result cache of *Q2* is invalidated.

INSERTS and DELETES would invalidate all query caches for table

The flaw of this method is that i. e. *Q1* is invalidated by *Q3* because there was no analysis of selection conditions that result in an empty intersection set.

**Question**

Is there any solution to check if conditions of two queries overlap or contradict each other so not all queries need to be invalidated depending on the query conditions?